# Set MimeType on Play Framework

Tags: html, video, playframework, playframework-2.0, mime-types

I try to serve HTML5 Video through a Play JAVA Application.

It works everywhere but it does not work on Safari. The format is OK since I can drag it and drop it in the Window and it actually plays.

The only difference I can see it is the following.

Working: (Check the type)

[image]

Not working: (Check the type)

[image]

I tried:

```
public static Result getMp4()


 {

     response().setContentType("video/mp4");


     return ok(new
java.io.File("path"));


 }
```